# How can I check equivalency between two arrays in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays

So I have two arrays and I need to find a way to find the equivalency between two different arrays in C++. This is the function I made:

```
    bool equivalent(int a[], int b[], int n)
        for (int i=0; i < n; i++){
            if (b[(i + 2) % 5] == a[i])
            return true;
            else return false;
        }
    }
```

and this is the array:

```
    int main() {
    cout << boolalpha; 
    int a1[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int a2[5] = {3, 4, 5, 1, 2};
    cout << equivalent(a1, a2, 5) << endl;
```

I know my arthmetic is correct, because for example, a2[4], 4 plus 2 is 6, mod 5 is 1, and in the a1[0] position, there is a value of 2 which is the same as the a2[4] value. My only problem is, the resultant should be true, but because the for loop starts at 0, the whole function messes up, as the second arrays index would need to start at a different number for it to work. How would I go about solving this?

Comment: What do you mean by equivalency? That they have the same elements? Is the order of elements pre-determined in both arrays?

Comment: Unrelated: You have no defense against the `n==0` case not returning a value.

Comment: Unrelated: `(b[(i + 2) % 5]` should probably be `(b[(i + 2) % n]` to generalize the algorithm.

Comment: I basically want to check if array of a2 can be shifted so that the two arrays match up. So if you shift all the elements in a2 two to the right, the elements would match up. So a2[0] is equal to a1[2], a2[1] is equal to a1[3], a2[2] is equal to a1[4] etc.

Comment: If that's the case, you don't want to return false right away. You want to return false only when all possibilities are exhausted without returning true.

Answer (score 0):

> How would I go about solving this?

By using a debugger. Step through the program line by line. If the behaviour is different than it is supposed to, you've found the problem.

There are two problems with the program:

> I know my arthmetic is correct, because for example, a2[4], 4 plus 2 is 6, mod 5 is 1, and in the a1[0] position, there is a value of 2 which is the same as the a2[4] value.

1. But you're comparing a1[0] with a2[2], not with a2[4]. You've got the order of the arguments reversed.
2. You only compare a1[0] and then return the result. In order to compare the entire array, you must not return until all elements have been checked (except the branch which returns false can return early).

Answer (score 0):

I think easy way is to convert both array into string  then compare both.